# Does deleting domain and removing property from Google Search Console remove a website from search results?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search

I had a staging site and added it to my Google Search Console and got it indexed. Now I deployed the site to my main domain. I also deleted the old subdomain / staging domain, and deleted the subdomain property from Google Search Console, but it's still showing the subdomain in Google Search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting a domain will quickly get a site removed from search results.  Google will remove each page on the domain after crawling it and getting an error, usually with a 24 hour grace period unless it is removed with a "410 Gone" error. It may take Google a few weeks to remove the entire site, but some pages will usually start getting de-indexed within a day or two.

Removing your Google Search Console property has no impact on whether or not your site is indexed.  Google indexes sites that exist but which are not verifified in Google Search Console.  Google also decides not to index sites that are verified in Google Search Console.  When you are removing your site, I would recommend keeping your Google Search Console account because:

- It will let you see how much of your site is still indexed after you deleted it.
- You could submit a temporary sitemap to get Googlebot to come crawl the site more quickly and find that all the pages don't exist.

Comment: thanks for answering, but it have been more than 48 hours since the domain was deleted, and website property was removed from google search console, but still Google is indexing the website.

Comment: It will likely take 2 weeks for Googlebot to crawl most of the pages on your site.  If you have a lot of pages, it could take several months to get to all of them. You should get your Google Search Console site verification back so that you can monitor the process and submit a temporary sitemap for any URLs that haven't been deindexed yet.

Comment: all pages got removed on the very first day after deleting domain, but there is only the home page, that is getting indexed. Isn't there any way to  de-index it ?

Comment: It will get removed, but it may take a couple weeks.  In the mean time you could redirect the old staging subdomain to your main domain.